# How to make contenteditable save permanently and globally?

Tags: javascript, php, html, contenteditable

I am trying to create a page which is very similar to Goodle-Docs, where everybody with access to the page will simply be able to edit the text. However my problem is that I can only get these changes to save locally, how do I make users edit the content-editable text so that the change is visible on all devices?

I am using this tutorial, http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/06/allowing-users-to-edit-text-content-with-html5/ but the changes of the page are only saved locally.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function saveEdits() {
  //get the editable element
  var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");
  //get the edited element content
  var userVersion = editElem.innerHTML;
  //save the content to local storage
  localStorage.userEdits = userVersion;
  //write a confirmation to the user
  document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";
}

function checkEdits() {
  //find out if the user has previously saved edits
  if(localStorage.userEdits!=null)
    document.getElementById("edit").innerHTML = localStorage.userEdits;
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="checkEdits()">

<div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
Here is the element
</div>

<input type="button" value="save my edits" onclick="saveEdits()"/>
<div id="update"> - Edit the text and click to save for next time</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you shouldn't use localStorage but a database, mysql for example. By the use of localStorage only the client editing will see the changes.

Comment: @Daan is right, use DataBase to store the several changes, and using AJAX retrieve them at runtime.

Comment: Got it, so I managed to create a MySQL table but I don't know how to make a form or retrieve the information. Is there some good tutorial or video on how to do this? I'm new and just getting out of wordpress

Comment: Why use a database to save arbitrary data?  You're just going to end up with a table with an `id` and `content` column with one row for this example.  It would be far easier (and accomplish the same thing) to save the raw HTML to a text file (with PHP), then load the contents of that with XHR.  **Unless** you want multiple pages to be editable, this is the quickest way to go.

Comment: Well I am planning on a similar setup to google docs, with 3 columns. Title, ID and Content, it'd be at least 4 different pages with editable text

Comment: But can you give me a sample code on how to achieve this with say: Index and test.txt files?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a back-end to sync content between users, and then poll the changes to each user with AJAX.

Personally I'd recommend checking out these javascript libraries and frameworks, as they contain features close to what you're trying to achieve out-of-the-box: [ShareJS](http://sharejs.org/), [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/) and [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Just like Waiski was saying...

this is pretty old, but I would like to point out...

You are able to do this through localStorage.setItem( //itemname, //contents ),
then to fetch it, localStorage.getItem( //itemname ). for more info check out [Mozilla localStorage...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You can do this temorarly but not recommended.

Good Day!

p.s. it may not work here due to not allowing you to setItem under stackoverflow because of a SecurityError, but check it out yourself!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
 
  var version = 0;
  
function saveEdits() {
  
  var editElem = document.getElementById("edit");
  version = localStorage.getItem("v");
  var versionTxt = document.createTextNode("Version " + localStorage.getItem("v"))
  document.body.appendChild(versionTxt);   
  version++
  
  localStorage.setItem("v", version);
  localStorage.setItem("Elm", editElem.innerHTML);
  
  
  
  document.getElementById("update").innerHTML="Edits saved!";
}

 var editedElem = document.getElementById("edit");
 var edits = localStorage.getItem("Elm");
 editedElem.innerHTML = edits;
 

</script>

</head> 

<body>
  <div id="edit" contenteditable="true">
 Edit me
</div>

<button onclick="saveEdits()">save edits</button>
<div id="update"> - Edit the text and click to save for next time</div>

</body>

</html>
```